# Multiple cell referencing and average

Tags: excel, average, cell-array

I'm a student who's currently going through exams and to help revise I'm making a spreadsheet to keep track of all the marks I've got for questions in example questions.

REFER TO SCREENSHOT & SPREADSHEET DOWNLOAD

I need the average percentage correct to be calculated for each topic.

[Download of the spreadsheet for you to test](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByXealpoAYe3TkYzTXpGT3FRazg?usp=sharing)

[Screenshot of the spreadsheet I've set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSCKD.png)

Comment: Look into AVERAGEIFS()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you already have the count of each question in column 'P' then that is helpful.

You can use **SUMIF(G:G,O29,J:J)/P29** to calculate that percentage for each cell in column 'Q'. Once you enter that formula into that cell then simply drag it up and down to fill up all your desired cells in column 'Q'.

You may notice that you will run into a DIVISION BY ZERO error. You can avoid this by surrounding the SUMIF function with an IF function that will simply display a blank cell rather than try to calculate anything if the count of questions is ZERO.

**EXAMPLE: IF(P29=0 , "" , sumif(...)   )**

Note: Once you auto drag the equation choose "fill without formatting" to keep your formatting clean.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked great :)